# Bash function from another script error handler

Tags: bash

I have the following situation. Script A source script B. Script B has a function named check, which does no error handling on any of its executed commands.

```
check () {
  cmd1
  cmd2
  cmd3
  ...
}
```

My goal is to call the function check from A, exiting if any of cmd* fails.

I have tried from A "check || exit 1" but if cmd2 fails and cmd3 succeeds, A does not exit. set -e did not do the job for me as well.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `set -e` seems to work for me. Please, give us more details.

Comment: "If a compound command or shell function executes in a context where -e is being ignored, none of the commands executed within the compound command or function body will be affected by the -e setting, even if -e is set and a command returns a failure status." https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#The-Set-Builtin

Comment: you can do `cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3 ...` in check, "check || exit 1" should work then.

Comment: @miken32 : can you point us to where the "context where -e is being ignored" is described/defined? Thanks and Good luck to all.

Answer (score 2):

You can try a custom exit function.

With fileA :

```
#!/bin/bash
source fileB
check
```

and fileB :

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a exitcode

check() {
  cmd1
  cmd2
  trap finish EXIT
}

cmd1() { 
  myexit 1
}

cmd2() {
  myexit 0
}

myexit() {
  exitcode+=$1
}

finish() {
  [[ ${exitcode[*]} =~ 1 ]] && exit 1  || exit 0
}
```

Then :

```
$ ./fileA; echo $?
1
```

The exit codes are appended in an array that is checked on exit in the `finish()` function.

Answer (score 2):

I figure it out. The problem was that if I "set -e" and call the function "func || exit 1" then func subcommands will continue even if cmd1 fails. Calling simply "func" does the trick.